# Joining two data frames together based on quarters and years

Tags: r

I have two data frames I want to join together. I have a series of `dates` and I want to join a `quarter` at time `t` up with its `t+1` `quarter`.

I get a little stuck at quarter 4, joining up with the `year + 1`. i.e. `Q4` of `2006` should be joined with `Q1` of `2007`.

The data I have is that I have an event which occurs once per year, say `February 15th 2006` and another event which occurs `March 3rd 2006`. At the end of March I collect all the events together and then obtain a number between `1` and `5` for each document. I want to the track the monthly performance over the next 3 months (or in quarter 2 in this case).

Then I take the events which happened between `April` and `June` and track these from `July` - `Sept`.

Then take all the events which happened between `July` and `September` and track the performance from `Oct` to `Dec`.

Take all the events which happened between `Oct` and `Dec` and track the performance from `Jan t+1` to `Mar t+1`.

How can this be done?

```
library(lubridate)

dates_A <- sample(seq(as.Date('2005/01/01'), as.Date('2010/01/01'), by="day"), 1000)
x_var_A <- rnorm(1000)

d_A <- data.frame(dates_A, x_var_A) %>%
  mutate(quarter_A = quarter(dates_A),
         year_A = year(dates_A))


dates_B <- sample(seq(as.Date('2005/01/01'), as.Date('2010/01/01'), by="day"), 1000)
x_var_B <- rnorm(1000)

d_B <- data.frame(dates_B, x_var_B) %>%
  mutate(quarter_B = quarter(dates_B),
         year_B = year(dates_B),
         quarter_plus_B = quarter(dates_B + months(3)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is to combine your year and quarter and join based on that.
Your code already includes the quarter +1, so adding a line to each of your calls to `mutate()` and then using joining based on the new column.

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

dates_A <- sample(seq(as.Date('2005/01/01'), as.Date('2010/01/01'), by="day"), 1000)
x_var_A <- rnorm(1000)

d_A <- data.frame(dates_A, x_var_A) %>%
      mutate(quarter_A = quarter(dates_A),
             year_A = year(dates_A),
             YearQ = paste(year_A, quarter_A))
dates_B <- sample(seq(as.Date('2005/01/01'), as.Date('2010/01/01'), by="day"), 1000)
x_var_B <- rnorm(1000)

d_B <- data.frame(dates_B, x_var_B) %>%
      mutate(quarter_B = quarter(dates_B),
             year_B = year(dates_B),
             quarter_plus_B = quarter(dates_B + months(3)),
             YearQ = paste(year_B, quarter_plus_B))

final_d <- left_join(d_A, d_B))
```